# DriveApp Access Denied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a Google Script attached to a Form that does a whole bunch of different things, but ultimately creates a couple of copies of a sheet.

The process has been working great for months, but recently I have been getting the following error when using the File.makeCopy method (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname-destination)

```
 function createTest()
{
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID");
  templateFile.makeCopy("NAME", DriveApp.getFoldersByName("FOLDERNAME").next())
}
```

> Access Denied: Drive App (on the templateFile.makeCopy line)

I have ensured that the Drive scope is added and there are no GSuite settings that could cause this(such as the DriveApp being disabled).

I cannot find a good answer as to why this would have stopped working over the last few days. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: What scope is added to the appsscript.json (manifest) file?

Comment: 1.What's the name? 2. What's the destination? 3.Do you have access to the destination? 4.Do you have enough free space in Drive? 5.How many sheets have you created/day? 6. Can you manually make a copy (1)with the same name and (2)in the same destination?

Comment: Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive (among others). - 
Name/Destination: No name or destination changes have made this work yet. I have full access to the destination. - 

Manual copy works fine with the name and destination copied from the method. 
- 
Drive space isnt an issue, deleted everything from the destination and issue persists. - Sheets created this way, ~10.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this leads to the direct solution, can you provide the latest script with the issue? Of course, please remove the personal information from it. By the way, you can retrieve the filename and fileId of the file using DriveApp?

Comment: Have you tried running a simple syntax with driveapp in another script? is this producing the same error?

Comment: I created a blank new script and copied my script above and it still gives the same error.

Comment: [Edit] to add your code. Quote the exact error message including line number.

Comment: Exact code added. Both getting the templateFile and the Folder both work independently.

Comment: 1.How about a generic `templateFile.makeCopy()` with no name and destination? 2.Does this work : `Logger.log(templateFile.getId())` 3.What else have you tried to resolve this problem?

Comment: Interesting. We recently (30/4/2019 4:28AM GMT)  started to receive this message "Access denied: DriveApp." on a folder.addFile() call in a script that has been running for more than a year now without problems. The app-script runs as the user that owns the folder. Cleaning up other files or changing the folder has not helped. It is as if the authorisation for the script to add files there has been forgotten. Problem still happening 2/5/2019 though we are working around it. For the moment it seems like a google service failure that cannot be solved . . . ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but as I had the exact same issue without an answer, I happened to use a wrong file id. So if you run this code, be sure to double check the accessed id(s).

Also: make sure the folder iterator in `DriveApp.getFoldersByName("FOLDERNAME").next()` actually **has** a next, thus there is a folder called "FOLDERNAME" inside your root folder. Else you would make a call on an undefined object.